# How many transitive S3-sets X are, up to isomorphism? Build action-tables

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I have done this same exercise for $Z_4$-set which I've found it way more intuitive. I know I have to think about this in an "abstract" way but I'm pretty lost. I do have the answer to it but still don't understand it.

Useful knowledge: 1) Any transitive $S_3$-set is isomorphic to the $S_3$-set of left cosets of some subgroup of $S_3$.
2) Two $S_3$-sets of left cosets of subgroups H and K are isomorphic if and only if they are conjugate.

Thoughts: Since $S_3$ has only 6 subgroups, there are at most 6 transitive $S_3$-sets. 3 of the subgroups of $S_3$ have order two (and can prove they are conjugate) which by 2) can conclude that there are exactly 4 transitive $S_3$-sets up to isomorphism.

**Now the real issue appears when I want to make the tables (for example the group applying to a set of 6 elements a,b,c,d,e,f):**

[image]

**How was this table constructed?**

As I said, doing these kind of tables is intuitive with $Z_4$ but not with $S_3$.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes you are correct, there are precisely four transitive $S_3$-sets up to isomorphism, and they all arise as actions on left cosets. The action you describe is on the left cosets of the trivial subgroup, which is equivalent to the action of $G$ on itself coming from Cayley's theorem. So the letters $a,\ldots,f$ just correspond to the six elements of the group, and it should be easy for you work out which letter corresponds to which group element.

Comment: Boss :D, thanks!